# How can i transform 3D scene into 2D using my own function

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

What I am trying to do is write a simple code, using function implement by myself, which allow me to rotate, translate, and scale the 2D picture of an 3D scene. I think I have already succeed to do most of the job, including projection. One thing that bother me is the question, why the objects I draw are so small? Also what I cannot do is the final step, where I actually project model into 2D image. I guess it has to do something with rendering.

there is my code :

````
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GL\freeglut.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const GLdouble cutleft = -10.0;
const GLdouble cutright = 10.0;
const GLdouble cuttop = 10.0;
const GLdouble cutbottom = -10.0;
const GLdouble cutnear = 25.0;
const GLdouble cutfar = 5.0;

const GLdouble TR[16] = {
    2 * cutnear / (cutright - cutleft),        0,                                        (cutright + cutleft) / (cutright - cutleft),    0,
    0,                                        2 * cutnear / (cuttop - cutbottom),        (cuttop + cutbottom) / (cuttop - cutbottom),    0,
    0,                                        0,                                        (cutfar+cutnear) / (cutfar-cutnear),            2*cutfar*cutnear/(cutfar-cutnear),
    0,                                        0,                                        -1,                                                0
};

GLfloat rotatex = 0.0;
GLfloat rotatey = 0.0;
GLfloat rotatez = 0.0;

GLdouble move = 0.0;

GLdouble scale = 1.0;

void klocek( int k)
{    

    int i = 0;
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3i(i, i, i);
        glVertex3i(i, i + k, i);
        glEnd();

        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3i(i, i + k, i);
        glVertex3i(i + k, i + k, i);
        glEnd();

        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3i(i, i + k, i);
        glVertex3i(i, i + k, i + k);
        glEnd();

        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3i(i, i, i);
        glVertex3i(i + k, i, i);
        glEnd();

        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3i(i + k, i, i);
        glVertex3i(i + k, i + k, i);
        glEnd();

        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3i(i + k, i, i);
        glVertex3i(i + k, i, i + k);
        glEnd();

        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3i(i, i, i);
        glVertex3i(i, i, i + k);
        glEnd();

        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3i(i, i, i + k);
        glVertex3i(i, i + k, i + k);
        glEnd();

        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3i(i, i, i + k);
        glVertex3i(i + k, i, i + k);
        glEnd();

        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3i(i + k, i + k, i + k);
        glVertex3i(i + k, i + k, i);
        glEnd();
    
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3i(i + k, i + k, i + k);
        glVertex3i(i, i + k, i + k);
        glEnd();

        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3i(i + k, i + k, i + k);
        glVertex3i(i + k, i, i + k);
        glEnd();

}

void ulica_prymitywow()
{

    glTranslatef(-5, 0, 0);
    klocek(3);
    
    glTranslatef(-1, 0, -4);
    klocek(4);

    glTranslatef(1, 0, -3);
    klocek(3);

    glTranslatef(10, 0, 7.5);
    klocek(2);

    glTranslatef(0, 0, -3);
    klocek(3);

    glTranslatef(0, 0, -4);
    klocek(4);
}

void move_scene()
{
    GLdouble T[16] = { 1, 0, 0, move,
                       0, 1, 0, 0,
                       0, 0, 1, 0,
                       0, 0, 0, 1 };

    glMultMatrixd(T);
};

void scale_scene()
{
    GLdouble T[16] = { scale, 0, 0, 0,
                       0, scale, 0, 0,
                       0, 0, scale, 0,
                       0, 0, 0, 1 };
    //mnożenie macierzy widoku
    glMultMatrixd(T);
}

void rotate_scene()
{
        double cosinusx = cos(rotatex);
        double sinusx = sin(rotatex);
        GLdouble Tx[16] = { 1,    0,            0,                0,
                           0,    cosinusx,    -sinusx,        0,
                           0,    sinusx,        cosinusx,        0,
                           0,    0,            0,                1 };
        glMultMatrixd(Tx);

        double cosinusy = cos(rotatey);
        double sinusy = sin(rotatey);
        GLdouble Ty[16] = { cosinusy,        0,        sinusy,            0,
                            0,                1,        0,                0,
                            -sinusy,        0,        cosinusy,        0,
                            0,                0,        0,                1 };
        glMultMatrixd(Ty);
 

        double cosinusz = cos(rotatez);
        double sinusz = sin(rotatez);
        GLdouble Tz[16] = { cosinusz,        -sinusz,        0,        0,
                           sinusz,            cosinusz,        0,        0,
                           0,                0,                1,        0,
                           0,                0,                0,        1 };
        glMultMatrixd(Tz);

}

void Display()
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glLoadIdentity();


    glTranslatef(0, 0, -(cutnear + cutfar) / 2);

    rotate_scene();

    move_scene();
    
    scale_scene();

    ulica_prymitywow();

    
    glFlush();

    glutSwapBuffers();

}

void Reshape(int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMultMatrixd(TR);
    Display();
}

void Keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{

    if (key == 'n')
        move += 0.01;
    
    else if (key == 'm')
        move -= 0.01;
    
    else if (key == '+')
        scale += 0.01;
    
    else if (key == '-')
        scale -= 0.01;

   
    Reshape(glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH), glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT));
}

void SpecialKeys(int key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
        
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
        rotatey -= 0.1;
        break;

    case GLUT_KEY_UP:
        rotatex -= 0.1;
        break;

    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
        rotatey += 0.1;
        break;

    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
        rotatex += 0.1;
        break;

    case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_UP:
        rotatez += 0.1;
        break;

    case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_DOWN:
        rotatez -= 0.1;
        break;
    }

    Reshape(glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH), glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT));
}

enum
{
    EXIT
};

void Menu(int wartosc)
{
    switch (wartosc)
    {
    case EXIT:
            exit(0);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);

    glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);

    glutCreateWindow("Ulica prymitywów");

    glutDisplayFunc(Display);

    glutReshapeFunc(Reshape);

    glutSpecialFunc(SpecialKeys);

    glutKeyboardFunc(Keyboard);

    glutCreateMenu(Menu);

    glutAddMenuEntry("Exit", EXIT);

    glutAttachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}; ```
````

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You have to transpose the matrices. Especially `move_scene`:

```cpp
void move_scene()
{
    GLdouble T[16] = { 1, 0, 0, 0,
                       0, 1, 0, 0,
                       0, 0, 1, 0,
                       move, 0, 0, 1 };

    glMultMatrixd(T);
};
```

OpenGL matrices are stored with column major order. The lines in your code are not rows, they are columns:

```
column 1:  { 1, 0, 0, 0,
column 2:    0, 1, 0, 0,
column 3:    0, 0, 1, 0,
column 4:    move, 0, 0, 1 };
```

Comment: @afra See[`gluPerspective`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml) and [LearnOpenGL - Camera](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera)